# Need help to create a simple login for a node-webkit application

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, authentication, node-webkit

I am totally stumped on this project.... I am attempting to create a node-webkit application witch required a login feature. I dont need a sign up. I need just a user and pass input that i can enter in the information that is defined in a text file or something.. literally does not need any function other than login with predefined user and pass of witch has multiple logins pre-defined in a text file or json, and to parse the name of the individual into text on the application based on the information provided into the form.. I know that an odd request but thats the job and i am quite stummmmmped! Any help pointing me in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:
`function login(){<br>
     var id={"name":"User Name",<br>
         "pw":"User Password"};<br>
     var user_id=prompt("User Name:")<br>
     if (user_id!=null){<br>
        var user_pw=prompt("Password:");<br>
     }if (user_pw!=null){<br>
        if(user_id == id.name && user_pw == id.pw){<br>
        window.open("//"); // open html website or file<br>
     }else{<br>
        alert("Error Password or Username!")}}}`

---

Call in Html:
    `a href="#' onclick="login()"`
Good Luck with your project! =)
Hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Sorry, please ignore the `<br>`

Comment: I havent been on in a long while. I used your method and it worked perfectly. Im sorry for not marking your answer I could of swore i did lol